# Newly Added Classes Not Behaving As The Ones Loaded on DOM Ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using **timeago.js**, a jQuery plugin to show that an article was posted `2 minutes ago`.

**HTML:**

```
<p> Articles <span class='post-time' title='2014-12-03 13:42'></span> </p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.post-time').each(function(){
    var $this = $( this );
    $this.timeago();
})
```

This works on classes that are loaded on DOM ready and I have a result that look like this:

First Article: *less than 1 minute ago*

Second Article: *4 minutes ago*

Third Article: *1 hour ago*

But the ones loaded via AJAX are not working. They don't show anything.

What do I do to make it work?

Comment: After you add the elements again you have to call timeago() on the new elements

Comment: `$('.post-time:first').timeago();` in your ajax success/complete, assuming the latest one is getting prepended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick suggestion is:

```
$.ajax({
     ...
     success:function(){
       // code for prepending
       $('.post-time:first').timeago();
     },
     complete:function(){
        // even you can call it here too.
     }
});
```

#### or:

make a global function and call it in your ajax success:

```
function setTimeago(){
    $('.post-time').each(function(){
        var $this = $( this );
        $this.timeago();
    });
}

$.ajax({
     ...
     success:function(){
       // code for prepending
       setTimeago(); // call here then
     },
     complete:function(){
        // even you can call it here too.
     }
});
```